# What does "to register" mean in terms of programming?

Tags: terminology

I am familiar with processor registers, but I'm a little confused about how the author of this programming ebook is using the word:

"When you opened this e-book, it was the result of computations within the system which allowed you to launch the application, click the e-book have it *register* when you clicked the ebook, turn the pages, and so on."

Now, i have a nagging suspicion this either has to do with processor registers or the windows registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`register` in this case refers to the capturing of the *action* of a button being clicked, after which other code can be executed. It has nothing to do with processor registers or windows registry.